# What type of singularity is $z=0$ for $f(z)=1/{\cos\frac{1}{z}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, singularity

> Consider the function $\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{1}{\cos\frac{1}{z}}$. Test what kind of singularity at $z=0$ ?

For singularities of $f(z)$ , $\cos \frac{1}{z}=0\implies z=\frac{2}{\pi (2n+1)}$. Now $z=0$ is also a singularity of $f$ and $0$ is the limit point of poles.

$\bullet$ So from a known theorem (which stated as , "*Limit point of poles is an essential singularity*") , $0$ is an essential singularity of $f$.

$\bullet$ **Definition : (from the book : *Functions of One Complex Variables by J.B. Conway*)** An **isolated singularity** of $f$ is said to be an *essential singularity* of $f$ if it is neither a pole nor a removable singularity of $f$.

$\bullet$ Again , from the singularities of $f$ it is clear that $0$ is a **non-isolated** singularity , as in any neighbourhood of $0$ there is also a singularity of $f$ other than $0$.

$\bullet$ Thus we get , $0$ is a **non-isolated essential** singularity of $f$. Which violates the definition of the **Essential singularity**.

Where my fallacy ? Please detect and rectify..

Comment: How exactly are you concluding that $0$ is an essential singularity?

Comment: What is the "known theorem"?

Comment: $\cos(1/z)$ has an isolated essential singularity at $z=0$, hence $1/\cos(1/z)$ has a singularity at $z=0$, but it is not isolated since there are arbitrary close poles around it, I would call it a "non isolated" essential singularity

Comment: @Eric Wofsey) As limit point of poles is an essential singularity

Comment: so an essential singularity doesn't have to be an isolated singularity...

Comment: @ user1952009) Please see my definition of essential singularity.

Comment: If your definition of essential singularity requires that they be isolated, then it is certainly not true that a limit point of poles is an essential singularity...

Comment: As I read this I agree with the others, in my experience requiring essential singularities to be isolated is not standard, though removable and poles often are (removable really are just continuity points we're being silly about, though). Can you clarify if you **require** a singularity to be isolated in order for it to be essential? Or can a non-isolated singularity (in your definitions) also be called "essential"?

Comment: what definition of an essential singulariity ? you didn't write any, and there is one https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_singularity not requiring the singularity to be isolated, even if specifying if the singularity is isolated or not is a good idea in this context

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 see my edit for perhaps a more complete outline of the objections we are raising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the characterization based on limits. A removable singularity has a limit at the given point. A pole happens when the function is unbounded near the point. An essential singularity happens when neither come to pass. So at $0$ since $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty} \cos(x)$ does not exist, clearly that singularity is essential since it does not converge to a limit, and it is not unbounded on the real axis.

---

**Written after the question was edited**

Your fallacy is using the word "isolated" when you don't really mean that:  in you case it seems you mean the adjective "essential" to only be applicable to isolated singularities. However, this seems to be in direct conflict with this "known theorem" you allude do, since clearly a limit of singularities can **never** be isolated. As such, I think the most reasonable interpretation of your question falls into the original answer I posted, but with the definition of "essential singularity" you give, there is no terminology defined for a "non-isolated essential singularity."

In short:  your question cannot be answered as-stated, but this "known theorem" seems to indicate it's most likely your class admits non-isolated essential singularities as a thing.

Comment: after looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_singularity they don't assume an essential singularity is isolated, but only that the function is holomorphic on $U$ and that $U$ has a non empty intersection with the neighborhoods of the  singularity, so yes it is an essential singularity under this definition

Comment: you don't understand the question of the OP ? how to classify singularities, the fact that it is isolated or not is important

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 : there are 2 types of essential singularities : isolated an non isolated, what do you want more ? see wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_singularity

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 yes, and I have addressed that in my answer. Anything more definite **cannot** be answered by me or **anyone** unless you are able to clarify those definitions with your teacher.

Comment: @ Adam Hughes) I understand your answer..According to your answer , " If limit of $f$ exists finitely at $z=a$ then $f$ has removable singularity at $a$. If limit exists finitely or infinitely (i.e. in $\mathbb C_{\infty}$ ) then $f$ has pole at $a$ . If limit does not exist finitely or infinitely then $f$ has essential singularity at $a$. Am I correct ?

Comment: @ Adam Hughes) One more question : If $f$ has non-isolated singularity at $z=a$ then is it true that $f$ has essential singularity at $z=a$ ?

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 to your first question:  yes, to your second:  that depends on what definitions you are using.

Comment: Ok...got it....

Comment: $f(z)=e^{1/z}$ has isolated essential singularity at $z=0$, which actually fits your definition.