# What type of singularity does $\displaystyle \frac{z-1}{exp(\frac{2\pi i}{z})-1}$ have at $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

**My answer:** Since $\infty$ is an essential singularity of $e^z \implies 0$ is an essential singularity of $e^{\frac{1}{z}}$.

I am assuming that it is also true that $0$ is an essential singularity of $\frac{1}{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}$. If so, it would be enough evidence that $0$ is essential singularity of $\displaystyle \frac{z-1}{exp(\frac{2\pi i}{z})-1}$ right?

Comment: Consider $z=1/k$,

Comment: @KushalBhuyan If I am correct, I believe by using $z=1/k$ and taking limit $k \to \infty$ we can show that no limit exists fr the given function hence it has to be an essential singularity???

Answer (score 1):

> $0$ is not a pole of ${e^{1\over z}}$

Proof:
$$
{ e^{1\over z}}=1+{1\over z}+{1\over2z^2}+\cdots
$$
$z^n{e^{1\over z}}$ is not continuous and therefore not holomorphic in an open set containing $0$ for any $n\in\mathbb N$.

> $0$ is not a removable singularity of ${e^{1\over z}}$

Proof:
$$
z\in\mathbb{R}_{\ge0}\implies\lim_{z\to 0}{e^{1\over z}}=+\infty
$$
Therefore, $e^{1\over z}$ is not bounded in a deleted neighborhood of $0$. So using [Riemann's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann.27s_theorem) we conclude $0$ is not a removable singularity of $e^{1\over z}$.

> Conclusion

$0$ is an essential singularity of ${e^{1\over z}}\;$.

You can show in a similar manner $e^{2\pi i\over z}-1$ has an essential singularity at $0$ and using [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/167646) you can show $1/(e^{2\pi i\over z}-1)$ has an essential singularity at $0$.

Edit: As the commentators note below, $z={1\over k}$ is also a singularity of $1/(e^{2\pi i\over z}-1)$ for all $k\in\mathbb N$ and therefore $0$ is a non-isolated essential singularity.

Comment: (+1) It is worth mentioning that the singularity is isolated.

Comment: @robjohn : you mean not isolated, since it looks like $\frac{1}{\cos( i \pi/z)}$, in another post we discussed a long time and decided to call those non-isolated essential singularity http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1806582/what-type-of-singularity-is-z-0-for-fz-1-cos-frac1z/1806584