# Singularity of the function $f(z)=\sin\left(\cos\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)\right)$ at the point $z=0$ is ...

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, proof-verification, singularity

> For the function $f(z)=\sin(\cos(\frac{1}{z}))$, the point $z=0$ is
>
> (a) a Removable singularity
>
> (b) a pole
>
> (c) an essential singularity
>
> (d) Non-isolated singularity

I have written Laurent's series expansion  $f(z)=\sin(1-\frac{1}{2!z^2}+\frac{1}{4!z^4}-\frac{1}{6!z^6}+...)= (1-\frac{1}{2!z^2}+\frac{1}{4!z^4}-\frac{1}{6!z^6}+...)-\frac{(1-\frac{1}{2!z^2}+\frac{1}{4!z^4}-\frac{1}{6!z^6}+...)^3}{3!}+...$
all the negative powers coming in the expansion. so singularity with respect to zero is an essential singularity. Am I correct? Please help me to judge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not correct. For two reasons:

1. the Laurent series of $\cos\left(\frac1z\right)$ at $0$ is$$1-\frac1{2!z^2}+\frac1{4!z^4}-\cdots;$$
2. you did not prove that the negative powers do not cancel each other after a certain point.

You can prove that it is indeed an essential singularty using the Casorati-Weierstrass theorem: since $0$ is an essential singularity of $\cos\left(\frac1z\right)$, if $V$ is a neighborhood of $0$, then the set $W=\left\{\cos\left(\frac1z\right)\,\middle|\,z\in V\setminus\{0\}\right\}$ is a dense subset of $\mathbb C$ and, since $\sin$ is non-constant entire function, $\sin(W)$ is dense. Therefore, $0$ must be an essential singularity of your function.

Comment: Thank you for pointing mistake.

Comment: Today I was trying to understand the proof. I understood everything but I am not able to see why $sin(W)$ being dense implies that $0$ must be an essential singularity of the function.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the alternatives? Well, $0$ could be a removable singularity. Or a pole. But in both cases, if you take a small neighborhood $U$ of $0$, then $f\bigl(U\setminus\{0\}\bigr)$ would *not* be dense in $\mathbb C$. Since it is…

Comment: ...it is a isolated singularity. Am I right?

Comment: That should be obvious. No: it is an essential singularity.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the limit $\lim_{z \to 0} \cos(1/z)$ does not exist. Therefore the singularity is of essential type.

Comment: consider $\frac{1}{z}$limit at $0$ , doesn't exists. But it is pole, right?

Comment: @Maneesh_Narayanan If a point  $z = z_0$ is a pole of $f (z) $, then $\lim_{z \to z_0} f (z) = \infty $.

Comment: Ok. I got the point. Thank You. Is that enough to show that limit at that point is neither 0 or infinity and limit doesn't exists, in order to prove some point is an essential sigularity?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1806582/what-type-of-singularity-is-z-0-for-fz-1-cos-frac1z?rq=1

Comment: this one is essential right?

Comment: @Maneesh_Narayanan Yes.

Comment: Thank you for your help.